# Php how to unpack hexadecimal data

Tags: php, unpack

I have this:

```
0xC1 0x3A 0x00 0x01 0x5D 0xDA 0x47 0x53 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00, 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xF0 0xFC 0x12 0x00 0x00 0x00

struct FileInfo {
    unsigned char header;
    unsigned char size;
    unsigned char type;
    unsigned char subtype;
    unsigned short item;
    char itemName[50];
    unsigned short ItemCode;
}
```

I tried using unpack(), but it was unsuccessful

Comment: How was it unsuccessful?

Comment: var_dump( unpack("cheader/csize/ctype/csubtype/Sitem", $data) ); I dont know how to unpack char itemName[50]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To unpack everything, you can use the following:

```
$unpackedData = unpack('cheader/csize/ctype/csubtype/Sitem/c50itemName/SitemCode', $binData);
```

Comment: @Matt Jr.: Then your input doesn't conform to the struct above. There isn't enough data.